# Unable to make div responsive & Overlay

Tags: css, button, overlay, responsive

I'm having trouble making a div button responsive in a webpage. I have changed all pixel values to percentages and the problem still exists.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.testing {
  padding: 10% 10%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #009ac9;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.testing:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ac9;
  border-color: #009ac9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="testing">LOG IN</a>
</div>
```

Another problem is, I have a fullscreen overlay menu and I'd like to disable this button when the overlay is present. As of now, the button is still clickable when the overlay is present. I'd like to disable it: 
 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkiSL.png)

Comment: actuality I don't get it? what you want.?? you want the `.wrapper` to be 100% width.?? and about the second **Q** - please provide more of your code containing the menu and this button together.!

Comment: I would like the button to be responsive so that it scales down with the page, and if viewed on a mobile device. As of now, the size is not reduced for some reason. 
As for the overlay, the button code is the same I have mentioned above. And the overlay I use is this one: [link](https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the unit `vw`. Change your `font-size` to `3vw` and see what happens if you resize the page.

Comment: @Huelfe: Thank you, that fixed it! Now could you help me with the overlay problem? For some reason, this same element seem to be active even when the overlay is present.

Comment: You have to provide the full code. I think it's a positioning problem.

Comment: @Huelfe: Just figured it out! z-index was the property I was looking out for. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I think this will be helpful.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:9;
}

.testing {
  padding: 10% 10%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #009ac9;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  width:20%;
  min-width:50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.testing:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ac9;
  border-color: #009ac9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="testing">LOG IN</a>
</div>
```

And for the menu give `z-index:999;` to the `.overlay` in your Fullscreen Overlay menu style.I think it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you! vw property fixed the responsiveness problem and z-index fixed the overlay problem. !

Comment: @Inception `vw` is a complicated property with it always use `min width` as a fixed width. Did you check my code? in that, I have not used `vw`. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try vh in place of percentages, Hope it will Work and use media query also in responsive screen.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mediaquery